# session login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i was unable to create session using login control. It supposed to be put in submit button, so i convert to template and double click at the login button, write :

```
session ["username"] = UserName.text
```

Since the textbox id for username field is UserName, so i put UserName.text unfortunately the id is giving me error.

```
UserName does not exist in current context.
```

So, what should i do to keep the username in session. Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the full error message I think what you posted is a part of the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 Session["username"] = LoginCtrlID.UserName;
```

Eg:
Suppose your Login Control is:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
<LayoutTemplate>
  ...
 <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  ...
</LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Try to get like:

> Session["username"] = Login1.UserName;

Comment: Thank you minmin! You such a saver of the day. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
session ["username"= ((TextbBox) templatename.FindControl("Username")).Text;
```